# How come this equals & hashCode override does NOT cause an exception or error?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

When I compile and run the code below, I get the following results:

```
o1==o2 ? true
Hash codes: 0 | 0
o1==o2 ? true
Hash codes: 1 | 8
o1==o2 ? true
Hash codes: 7 | 3
o1==o2 ? true
Hash codes: 68 | 10
o1==o2 ? true
Hash codes: 5 | 4
```

From what I've read, if two objects are equal, their hashCodes must also be equal.  So, how does this code not cause an exception or error?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class EqualsAndHashCode {

    private int num1;
    private int num2;

    public EqualsAndHashCode(int num1, int num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x=0; x < 5; x++) {
            EqualsAndHashCode o1 = new EqualsAndHashCode(x, x);
            EqualsAndHashCode o2 = new EqualsAndHashCode(x, x);
            System.out.println("o1==o2 ? " + o1.equals(o2));
            System.out.println("Hash codes: " + o1.hashCode() + " | " + o2.hashCode());
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (this.getNum1() == ((EqualsAndHashCode)o).getNum1()) && (this.getNum2() == ((EqualsAndHashCode)o).getNum2());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (int)(this.getNum1() / Math.random());
    }

    public int getNum1() { return num1; }
    public int getNum2() { return num2; }
}
```

**EDIT I**
The premise behind my question was the wording surrounding the hashCode contract (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

I *assumed* that this rule would have been enforced by the JVM at compile or run time and I would have seen errors or exceptions right away when the contract was violated...

Comment: Where exactly would this error be thrown from?

Comment: I've read language in books that state if two objects are equal, their hashCodes MUST be equal...I guess I was expecting to see an error or exception thrown by the JVM with this code

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Comment: As the answers state, this is a recommendation. How would the JVM enforce such a thing, though? Should it randomly call `equals` and `hashCode` on any object in the environment during the application run? What if the calculations for equality have nontrivial implementations and consume a lot of CPU time?

Comment: @TomG - I like your points. I hadn't thought about those questions myself.

Comment: Actually you can break the rules, but expect random behavior then. That's why you have to be *always* careful when implementing `equals()` and `hashcode()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the JVM does not check or validate that the *method contract* holds true. They're just methods, and they can return whatever they want.

However, any code which depends upon them supporting the method contract might or will fail. You will not be able to use your `EqualsAndHashCode` objects in a `HashMap`, for example. That *will* throw exceptions or will not return correct values in most cases.

This is the same thing with `compareTo()` and `TreeMaps` - `compareTo()` can return any `int` that it wants, but if it doesn't return a consistent ordering as defined by the method contract in the `Comparable` interface, then your `TreeMap` will throw exceptions as soon as it detects inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2):

> if two objects are equal, their hashCodes must also be equal

**Above is a recommendation and is not mandated by JVM**

The idea behind this recommendation is to have less collisions when storing elements in a hashed collection such as HashMap.

A very good article on the need of hashcode, rules for equals and hashcode, etc:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html

Comment: I think you are confusing the OP statement with the one that says - *If hashcode are equal, the objects must also be equal*. B'coz your reasoning for making that mandatory is not correct.

Comment: @RohitJain I have mentioned, it is not mandated by JVM. JVM will never complain no matter how good or bad hashcode implentation is written. But as i mentioned, idea behind the recommendation is to have less collision in hashed collections. Good implementation will lead to O(1) complexity for getting objects from hashed collection.

Comment: Again you are giving explanation for the other way round problem. You are talking about the benefits of two unequal objects having unequal hashcodes. But the question is about - two equal objects having equal or unequal hashcodes. Both are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

> So, how does this code not cause an exception or error?

Well, breaking the contract of equals and hashcode, never throws an exception or error. It's just that you see weird behaviour, when you use the objects of those class in hash based collections, like - `HashSet`, or `HashMap`.

For example, if in your case, you use your class objects as *key* in a `HashMap`, then you might not be able to find that key again, when you try to fetch it. Because, then even if your keys are equal, their hashcodes might be different. And HashMap saerch for keys first using their *hashcodes*, and then using *equals*.

Answer (score 0):

How could they possibly be the same given the fact that you are dividing by a Random number?

The typical approach is to use the hashCode values of the individual fields to build the hashCode of the object (if they aren't primitive, in this case they are). You also typically multiply by several prime numbers.

```
// adapted from Effective Java
public int hashCode() {
   int p = 17, q = 37;

   p = q * p + num1;
   p = q * p + num2;

   return p;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of the correct way to override equals and hashCode as Bloch writes in Effective Java.  I guess I was (erroneously) expecting that if 2 objects were equal and their hash codes different that an exception or error would be thrown.

Comment: My point was they would be the same if you weren't dividing by a random number

Answer (score 0):

Use this for hasCose

```
 public int hashCode() {
    int result = num1;
    result = 31 * result + num2;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default implementation of hashcode() and equals() is inhertied from Object class by each of the class that you define.  In order for your code to behave correctly, especially when it is used in data structures such as HashMap, it is important that you "should" override the default implementation that ensures that "If two instances of your class are equal, then they return same value when hashCode() method is called".

Definition of equality of two objects depends on domain concept their classes represent, and hence, only the author of the class is best suited to implement "equals" and "hashcode" methods.  For example, two Employee objects are considered equal if they have same value for "employeeId" attribute.  These two may be different instances, but in the realm of domain (say, Human Resources System), they are equal due to equality of their employee IDs.  Now, the author of the Employee class should implement "equals" method that compares "employeeId" attributes and returns true if they are same.  Similarly, the author should ensure that hashCode() of two Employee instances are same if their employee IDs are same.

And if you are worried about how to write hashCode that meets the above Java recommendation, then, you can generate the hashCode and equals using Eclipse.

Though it is only a recommendation "if two objects are equal, their hashCodes must also be equal", you should be aware of the fact that your code can start misbehaving if objects of your class are used in Set, Map, etc. if you don't create "equals" and "hashCode" methods that comply with this recommendation.  Only time you would like to ignore this recommendation is when you are sure that your class will never be tested for equality.  An example of such class can be a DAO class or a Service class which typically is instantiated and used as Singleton, and no one (in normal scenarios) compares two DAO or Service classes

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of method contracts is in most cases to allow other code to assume that certain conditions will hold true.  In particular, the purpose of the `hashCode` and `equals` contracts is to allow a collection to assume that if an object `Foo` has a particular hashcode (e.g. 24601), and a collection of objects `Bar` is known not to contain any objects with that hashcode, one may infer from that information that `Bar` doesn't contain `Foo`.  As a bonus, if a collection of objects contains a variety of hashcodes including that of `Foo`, and if one has precalculated the hashcodes of all the objects in the collection, one may check the hashcode of each object against that of `Bar` before looking at the object itself.  Comparing two objects' already-computed hash values will be fast, no matter how complicated the objects are.

For all this to work, it is imperative that an object which will report itself equal to another object must *always* have reported the same hash code as that other object.  Because it is *always* possible to obey this rule, there is seldom any good reason to disobey it.  Even if the only immutable characteristic of an object which would be used in determining equality is its type, it's still possible to obey the rule by having all objects of that type return the same hash value.  Having objects which will always be different report different hash values may improve performance by several orders of magnitude, but given a choice between behavior which is slow but correct, and behavior which is fast but wrong, the former should generally be preferred.